# Block commands to a user

Tags: command-line

is there a way to block all terminal commands on user `leo` on ubuntu 22.04 except `cd`, `ls` and `pm2 restart`?

I tried adding `8Th09x34VEhh ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/pm2 restart RjbRTmVw` in `visudo` but it asks for `leo`'s password. I would like to ask the root one or "permission denied"

Comment: I'm not sure why did you use `visudo` as using this method, you can only restrict what commands can be executed if the user in question runs `sudo` or someone else runs `sudo` to that user's account. It doesn't restrict commands available to the user after "normal" login in any way.
You can do the later by giving the user a restricted shell and modifying appropriately their `PATH` variable to point to a directory where only a few available commands exist, but restricted shell by itself disables the use of `cd` command, so you cannot fully achieve what you want.